# how to add paragraphs or break in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
.Introduction = "Hello, this is line 1. This is line 2. This is line 3."
```

Can anybody suggest me a method to break this up into paragraphs. 
I have tried to using br but am unable to split the sentences up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vbNewline` or `vbCrLf`.

Your code should be like:

```vb
.Introduction = "Hello, this is line 1." & vbNewline & "This is line 2." & vbNewline & "This is line 3."
```

Comment: `Chr(10)` (line break character) would also work.